# Keyboard shortcut to jump between tabs on OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

In OS X Terminal.app, if you open new windows, you can easily switch between them with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd>, etc.

You can also cycle between tabs, using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>}</kbd>. (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd>)

But is there a way to jump straight to a particular tab, like you can with windows?  e.g. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd> to jump to the third tab?  (That's not it, of course.)

I'm pretty sure it's impossible out of the box, but what if I'm willing to write some AppleScript to make this work?

Comment: Just for reference: Shift-Command-Left/Right Arrow also switch tabs. And in Mac OS X Lion 10.7, you can use a three-finger swipe to switch tabs.

Comment: Three-finger swipe does not work in Mavericks (for me).

Comment: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>, etc. do not work in Mavericks.

Comment: `ctrl + tab` will nav you thru the terminal tabs in MacOS Sierra (and probably earlier)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ditch Terminal and use [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/).  It lets you do this and is, to me anyway, a bit more useful.

Comment: Winner! I just installed it and I already love iTerm's configurability (though it is a bit complex...)

Comment: With iTerm, the answer would be `command + T`, and `control + tab`, just like a browser. `command + W` closes a tab.

Comment: iTerm is relatively slow in comparison to the regular Terminal. But nonetheless, a good terminal emulator.

Comment: BTW `ctrl + tab` lets you change which tab you're on in terminal in OSX.

Comment: I would stick with Terminal and learn the below shortcut, iTerms latency is crazy : https://danluu.com/term-latency/

Comment: You can charge the Terminal shorcuts to match iTerm.

Comment: Consider using [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/), as iTerm 1 didn't get any updates since 2009

Comment: `iTerm2` is v buggy for pasting: after a long struggle I have regrettably reverted to `terminal`

Comment: This answer doesn't help

Answer (score 213):

The key combination is: <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Left or Right</kbd>

Comment: With this I no longer have a need for iTerm :)

Comment: Did the original question not ask for a way to switch to a **specific** tab (rather than to next or previous tab)?

Comment: This should be the accepted anwer

Comment: I was a little taken aback when I thought I would have to have to install iterm just to move between tabs......phew.

Comment: can we configure it ?

Comment: I can't believe it's easy yet.

Comment: On my machine, switching works with <Cmd>+<Left or Right>, rather than <Shift>+<Cmd>+<Left or Right>. I'm using MacOS "Mojave" (10.14.6).

Answer (score 25):

It can be done from <kbd>System Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Keyboard</kbd> > <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd> > <kbd>App Shortcuts</kbd> > click <kbd>+</kbd> > select `Terminal.app` and add the option title as it appears in the Terminal menu, which can be:

- <kbd>Select Next Tab</kbd> (on Mavericks and earlier)
- <kbd>Show Next Tab</kbd> (on Yosemite, El Capitan, Sierra...)

[image: Yosemite menu items]

**Note**: As you probably realize, you can do this with absolutely *any* [Cocoa] OSX app that has a menu with options, even if originally the app defined no shortcut for the option.

This kind of shortcuts are not equivalent to using native app shortcuts. What OSX is in fact doing is triggering the provided menu option via the label - you'll notice that while you press the keys the corresponding menu item will flash in the menu bar.

<sup>After years of resisting the idea of using a third-party terminal i finally switched to iTerm2 primarily because of properly working window split which in the ootb Terminal.app is not very useful. Also the shortcuts are fully configurable, making it possible to achieve anything you want, including switching to a specific tab with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[tab number]</kbd> to jump to the **N***th* tab.</sup>

Comment: Did the original question not ask for a way to switch to a **specific** tab (rather than to next or previous tab)?

Comment: @matty: you are right, the original question mentions switching to a *specific* tab, but the question _title_ is more generic than that, so most people who found this question were just looking for a way to easily switch tabs with an easier shortcut than OSX provides by default.

Answer (score 10):

In macOS High Sierra (10.13) you can switch to a specific tab using the shortcut keys <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> – <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>.

To enable/disable these shortcut keys, go to **Settings** > **General** and toggle **Use ⌘-1 through ⌘-9 to switch tabs**.

[image: Terminal Settings > General]

Answer (score 9):

I've been using [Spark](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305144205/http://www.shadowlab.org/softwares/spark.php) for years. It lets you overwrite shortcuts of any application, such as Terminal and Safari. I use it to make both programs switch tabs with **command+n** where **n** is the tab number, from 1 to 9.

After you download and copy Spark.app to `/Applications`, start it, click **All Applications' Hotkeys** to expand the menu on the left, and click on the plus sign to add new application.

Add Terminal (from `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`). Next thing is to create the shortcuts: click **File->New HotKey->AppleScript** (or just hit *command+1*). Click on the shortcut area and hit *command+1*, name it *tab1* and use this code:

```
tell front window of application "Terminal" to set selected tab to tab 1
```

Repeat it for *command+2* to *command+9*.
If you want the ability to vertically maximize the terminal, create a new shortcut like *command+shift+m*, name it whatever you want and use this code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set _b to bounds of window of desktop
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    tell front window
        set {_x, _y, _w, _h} to (get bounds)
        set _vz to item 4 of _b
        set bounds to {_x, 10, _w, _vz}
    end tell
end tell
```

Same thing for Safari on tab shortcuts, but the code is a bit different:

```
tell front window of application "Safari" to set current tab to tab 1
```

Honestly, I can't use either Terminal or Safari without this.

Comment: You can use osacompile to save scripts like this quickly: `for n in {1..9} -1; do osacompile -e "try" -e "tell app \"Terminal\" to tell window 1 to set selected tab to tab $n" -e "end" -o Select\ Tab\ $n.scpt; done`. Wrapping the scripts in try blocks prevents error dialogs. Spark was last updated in 2008; another application that allows assigning application-specific shortcuts to scripts is [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/).

Answer (score 5):

### Lesser known multi-application keyboard shortcuts

#### Bring the previous tab to the front

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd>

#### Bring the next tab to the front

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>

---

### Origin and scope

If I recall correctly, those were the shortcuts when Safari gained tabs.

Those original shortcuts are *not* in how-to HT201236 ([Mac keyboard shortcuts - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/HT201236)) but they *are* in [Safari 9 (El Capitan): Safari keyboard and other shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21483) and:

- both shortcuts are still good with other applications – such as Terminal – in release candidate 16A319 of Mac OS X 10.12 (macOS Sierra).

Answer (score 4):

I arrived here wanting an answer on how to change the shortcut for ANY application. @ccpizza's answer put me in the right direction.

Here's how I did it:

- Open "System Preferences" (From Apple menu top left corner of screen)
- Open "Keyboard"
- Select "App Shortcuts" on the left
- Press the `+` sign
- In the popup, choose "All applications"
- Enter "Show Next Tab" (without parentheses) and your desired shortcut
- Enter "Show Previous Tab" and your desired shortcut

You can do this for any menu item (top bar). OSx does a text search, so you just have to match it... And be lucky enough that all apps use the same naming :)

Comment: This works nicely. Now it has the same shortcut keys with the browser when I switch between tabs. And the new shortcuts also reflect in the `Terminal.app` --> `Window` dropdown.

Comment: Thank you, my friend for helping me change default shortcut!

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works fine as for now

Answer (score 0):

[Tab Switching in Terminal](http://ciaranwal.sh/2007/12/10/tab-switching-in-terminal) is the only way that I know. I haven't tested it with Snow Leopard so YMMV.

Or you can use [Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) and switch "tabs" with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>0-9</kbd> to switch directly to one.

Comment: This no longer appears to work in Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [How can I change the keyboard shortcut for switching tabs in Mac Terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/176177/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-tabs-in-mac-terminal/176181#176181)

1: Install `SIMBL` (plugin enabler): http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php

2: Install the `TerminalTabSwitching.bundle`

```
git clone https://github.com/dabeeeenster/terminaltabswitching
cp -r terminaltabswitching/TerminalTabSwitching.bundle "/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins"
```

3: Restart the Terminal app, and enjoy `Cmd+[0-9]` tab-switching.

**FYI:** It you received something like `plugin is not verified in terminal version # (a number)` when you opened your terminal again, maybe the following information would help.

(1) Open

```
/Library/Application\ Support/SIMBL/Plugins/Terminal/TerminalTabSwitching.bundle/Contents/Info.plist
```

using your favorite text editor under `sudo`.

(2) Search For `<key>MaxBundleVersion</key>`.

(3) Change `<string>280</string>` at next line to your terminal version number or higher like `<string>300</string>`. Save.

(4) Quit terminal and reopen it. Hopefully that prompt would disappear and you can use `Cmd+[0:9]` for tab switching.